# Accessing variable from differnet wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf

I could pass one variable to different window on creation but what is the best approach to be able to access everything from code-behind of new window to code-behind of parent window?

So far I have used popup with StaysOpen but the floating window became so complicated that I had to move it to the new window.

Comment: The best approach is not being able to access everything of a different class. What are you actually trying?

Comment: @NicoSchertler child window is settings/presets window and should be able to retrieve, display and save some parameters after user adjusts them in the parent window.

Comment: Then use a data object for the communication and pass that object to the child window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends exactly on what you need.

One option is when you create a new windows, set the owner. Something like:

```
FooWindow a = new FooWindow();
a.owner = this;
```

then from the FooWindow you can access owner, cast to the window you want and access all properties.

This is one solution...don't know if it's the best one!